# Magento 2: Details in checkout formatted with HTML-tags

Tags: magento2, cart, knockoutjs

For the title of an article, I am using HTML-code. 
Unfortunately, the HTML-code in the cart is not written as formatted in HTML – it is written with the HTML-tags, like:

```
"This is a title.<br>Yeah, really!"
```

The item is rendered with the following command in "details.html"

```
data-bind="html: full_view"
```

I would like to show it like this:

```
This is an title.
Yeah, really!
```

The template comes from here:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml
```

and looks like this:

```
<dl class="item-options">
 <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
  <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $block->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
   <dt><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
   <dd>
     <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
      <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?>
     <?php else: ?>
      <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
   </dd>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this? Many thanks!

The problem seems to be "echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view']" – but I do not understand where this value comes from. 
I really appreciate any hint!

Comment: Paste full code here?

Comment: Hello Supravat, sorry for the delay – here is the full code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write HTML in your description, it is important, that you're using the HTML-Editor (marked grey in my screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the HTML-tags are used in the product name. so, it is plain HTML there like the example above.

Comment: wait. do you want to use HTML in the name or description? because in the question you stated description

Comment: Hi Philipp, shame on me – yes, it is the title, not the description. Many thanks! I changed the text above.